# Cannot find method for iOS Native Development

Tags: ios, swift

I am going through a tutorial where a button and label is kept and to change the label text on click of button a method is called in tutorial

```
sender.titleForState(.Normal)
```

But in my Xcode, I cannot find the same method.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to change title of a `UIButton` in **Swift 3/4**

```
sender.setTitle("Your title", for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

try this

```
func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.setTitle("Your title", for: .normal)
}
```

And call this func by adding a selector like this

```
youbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourController.buttonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Add this to your viewDidLoad() method

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change button's title by click on button then you need to write code in button'e action method

Ex.

```
@IBAction func clickOnButtonForChangeTheTitle(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    sender.setTitle("I'm changing the title", for: .normal)
}
```